# How to query data from a function

Tags: python, sqlite, function

The function queries transactions from a database. I'm able to get them to work individually. Is there a way to make the function query the data based on say the customer name AND the date range without making another "if" statement?

```
def query_data(c, dateRange=None, customer_name=None, customer_id=None, customer_date=None):

    if customer_name is not None:
        query_where = 'customer_name=?'
        query_args = [customer_name]
        query_where = f'{query_where}'

    if customer_id is not None:
        query_where = 'customer_name=(SELECT customer_name FROM customers WHERE customer_id=?)'
        query_args = [customer_id]
        query_where = f'{query_where}'

    if customer_date is not None:
        query_where = 'order_date=?'
        query_args = [customer_date]
        query_where = f'{query_where}'

    if dateRange is not None:
        split_date = dateRange.split(",")
        query_where = 'order_date BETWEEN DATE(?) AND DATE(?)'
        query_args = [split_date[0], split_date[1]]
        query_where = f'{query_where}'

    query_string = f"SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE {query_where}"
    c.execute(query_string, query_args)
    return c.fetchall()
```

Comment: Put your subqueries in a list like `subqueries = ['subquery1', 'subquery2']` then compose the subqueries with `' AND '.join(subqueries)`.

Comment: Use an existing lightweight ORM or a SQL builder library (https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html, https://github.com/kayak/pypika).

Comment: Maurice is probably right. Depending on your usage, you need to be careful about SQL injection vulnerabilities and a malicious user wreaking havoc.